# Expected Identifier in Function Declaration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, methods

I am trying to write a simple init method on my custom UIButton class.

But it says:

> Expected Identifier in Function Declaration

My method is as below,

```
override func init(frame: CGRect) {

}
```

I searched loads of answers for this error, but without success.

Answer (score 3):

Leave out `func`:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i also tried , it then says  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

Comment: Yup, and that means (surprise!) that you also have to implement that initialiser. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't write `init` with the `func` keyword. You need to write it like this:

```
class myButton: UIButton {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

according to Apple docs:

> Every UIView subclass that implements an initializer must include an implementation of `init?(coder:)`. The Swift compiler knows this, and offers a fix-it to make this change in your code. Fix-its are provided by the compiler as potential solutions to errors in your code.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html